# How do I recognize if a dish cannot be cooked in a gas oven?

Tags: oven

I have moved to a house that has a gas oven. I am new to gas ovens. What dishes can we cook in a gas oven? Cake? Are cookies possible to bake in a gas oven?

Comment: What **can't** you cook in a gas oven?

Comment: Hello Bobby, and welcome to the site. We are not a discussion forum, and we don't take all types of questions. Especailly questions which are going to produce a list of equally good answers are closed here. Your original question asked for such a list, so would have had to be closed. But it so happens that such a list does not exist, and as Joe explained, you can bake anything. So I changed the title into something which does not invite people to post lists of things you can cook in your oven, but still can be answered with the correct explanation.

Comment: @rumtscho I don't think there was ever any real danger that people would start answering with lists of oven-cookable dishes.

Comment: @DavidRicherby wait until you have the rep to see the kind of answer I have to delete frequently. Not from the core users, but there are sufficient people driving by who just post such things. Editing it is a good prevention. Also it makes for one less precedent when somebody else posts a real big-list question and later points at this ones and says "it wasn't closed, why is mine closed".

Comment: Not owning any gas ovens: What is the range of temperatures that can be typically set and held in a gas oven?

Answer (score 13):

You can cook anything in a gas oven that you can cook in an electric oven.  There might be a little extra moisture (due to the products of combustion), but some people consider that to be an advantage when baking bread and cooking roasts.

Comment: If you've never had an oven before, the list of items is way too large to enumerate ... but if it calls for oven cooking, you can cook it.

Answer (score 3):

There are two answers to this question, both are right and they disagree with each other.

1. Some ovens are better for certain things, electric ovens are good for pastries, gas is better for roasts.
2. An oven is an oven. A skilled cook can cook a pineapple upside down cake or high tea over a campfire, wood fired pizza oven, or commercial stove with equal panache!

There are differences between types of ovens, and some ovens are superior for certain tasks, but any functional oven can be used to bake almost anything. (Some wood fired bread and pizza ovens are very difficult to cook large roasts in.)

Answer (score 2):

Everything can be cooked in a gas oven, but some things will be done differently. Anything thats needs heat from above (such as garlic bread) needs to be cooked in the broiler. That's the drawer at the bottom. Not a storage space!

Comment: This post is much more informative now.  You might want to note that not all broilers are under the stove... mine actually has a second heating element, so broiling is done in the same space and the under drawer actually is a storage space.